# What version of .NET does OTP.NET use?

Tags: one-time-password

1.1 or 2.0 runtime?

Also has anyone got any exprience using OTP.NET?

Comment: Could you provide a link to the DLL? A little investigation with reflector will likely reveal the answer.

Comment: Good idea though I don't have the DLL available and I'm too lazy to build the source and find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's last version uses .NET Framework 2.0.

Years ago I gave it a try. But that was not interesting to me those days. :(